# Find command not working when used in pipe

Tags: batch-file, command-line

```
echo off

:loop

tasklist /fi "imagename eq Notepad.exe" | find "INFO:" > nul

if errorlevel 1 goto loop

wordpad.exe
```

This is not working in XP. It works fine in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When notepad.exe does not exist in the task list, `tasklist /fi "imagename eq Notepad.exe"` dumps the "INFO:" line to stderr in Windows XP.  You could redirect stderr to stdout with `2>&1`, but it's easier just to `find /i "notepad"` instead.

On a side note, instead of doing `if errorlevel 1` you could use [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution).

```js
@echo off
setlocal

:loop

rem // Output nothing for the following code block.
>NUL 2>NUL (

    rem // Make sure notepad is not running before continuing.
    tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" | find /i "notepad" && (

        rem // Notepad is in tasklist.  Sleep 1 second, then check again.
        timeout /t 1 /nobreak || ping -n 2 localhost
        goto loop
    )
)

wordpad.exe
```